# Sharepoint Document's macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to upload an excel document with a few macros to a 2013 SharePoint, I don't know if I can use the macros via "View in Web Browser" option. I cant get them working, although if I download the document and I open it in Microsoft Office Excel, they work great.

I hope you can understand what's my problem

Comment: Are you asking if you can run macro's in an excel document if you view this excel workbook in a web browser?

Comment: Excel Web Services does not support VBA. If you need to run the macros you will have to open the file in Excel, not in the Web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You needed SharePoint's Excel Services to do this.

Not everything works of course so you need to read through the microsoft documentation and do some testing.

[Overview of Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee424405.aspx)